# Why is the button not appearing?

Tags: php, html, button

I'm a noob to coding.

This is what came with the theme in the content.php:

```
<div class="ct-button">
                    <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn"
                       <?php esc_html_e( 'read more' , 'untold' ); ?>> </a>
```

It was working fine before I started adding styles in the php file. Now, the button is not appearing at all, even though I've since eliminated my styling additions. Is there something missing?

Comment: because there is error in your `a` tag. proper would be `<a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn"><?php esc_html_e( 'read more' , 'untold' ); ?> </a>`

Comment: To add to what @PavelJanicek said, you misplaced the anchor text by including it in the opening tag, instead of putting it _in between_ the opening and closing tags.

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because you put the code `<?php esc_html_e('read more', 'untold'); ?>` inside the opening  tag. Just extract that part from the tag like this:

```php
<a href="<?=get_the_permalink()?>" class="btn">
   <?php esc_html_e('read more', 'untold'); ?>
</a>
```